# How to filter by two labels in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitor, promql

We have an `error_count` metric which have two labels:

1. client
2. error_code

Because we know that there is a client will have (let's say, 404 error_code) which can not be avoided, so we want to exclude it in our dashboard.

Something like:

```
error_count{client!="foo_client" and error_code!="404"}
```

But

```
error_count{client!="foo_client", error_code!="404"}
```

won't work because it will exclude all from `foo_client` and all `404` errors.

And for what's worse, I only have control on Grafana's PromQL, maybe config Prometheus' collecting can solve this but I have no permission to config this since they are managed by other teams.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, what you want is the `error_count` metric for *all* clients. If it's a `foo_client`, you only want it if it's *not* a 404 error code.

Here's one way to do that in Prometheus: get all entries that aren't `foo_client`, OR entries that *are* `foo_client` that don't have `error_code=404`:

```
error_count{client!="foo_client"} or error_count{client="foo_client", error_code!="404"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `or` which is an [union operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) in promQL.

```
error_count{client!="foo_client"}
or
error_count{error_code!="404"}
```

Comment: thanks, this can solve. But in the future we may need to add more, say, ``client=bar and error_code=403`` should be ignored as well. Is there an easy and maintainable way to do this? thanks.

Comment: The `or` is a great solution! For having specific combinations you could do: `error_count{client!="foo_client", client!="bar_client"} or error_count{client="foo_client",error_code!="404"} or error_count{client="bar_client",error_code!="403"}`. The first `error_count` matches all clients and all error codes, except `foo_client` and `bar_client`. Then the ones after with `or` add respectively the errors for `foo_client` with `error_code` 404 and those of `bar_client` with `error_code` 403.